# Python socket works over LAN but not over Wifi

Tags: python, windows, udp

I have a simple UDP server implemented in python:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(("",10005))

while True:
    data = sock.recv(1024)
```

I run this code on computer A.
I send UDP commands from computer B in these two situations:

1. Both A and B are connected to a router in a local network via LAN cable.
2. Both A and B are connected to router over Wifi.

The UDP packets are received in situaltion 1 (LAN Cable) but not in situation 2 (over Wifi).
**In both the cases Wireshark shows the received packet on computer A.**
Any thoughts?

OS: Windows

**The client program:**

```
import socket 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(char,("192.168.1.107",10005))
sock.close()
```

I have come close to finding the solution. Windows is dropping the UDP packets. I checked with `netstat -s -p UDP` command. Whenever the sending computer sends the UDP packets, the Receive Errors increase. Now I just have to figure out why the packets are being received erroneously.

**Edit**
I have tested it on other computers. It works. I have switched of the firewall on the computer where it doesn't work but still can not figure out what is filtering out the UDP packet.

Comment: What is the client program, and what version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7.
Simplified Client Program Used:
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.sendto(char,("192.168.1.107",10005))
sock.close()

Comment: Can you run `netstat -r` and show the output here.

Comment: the output is too long for the comment.. which part of the output do you want to see?

Comment: Hey OP, you can edit your question and add the output of `netstat -r` to make it easier to answer. I didnt know about that when I started using Stackoverflow.

Comment: Does the WiFi adapter have the same address as the TX adapter? Are you modifying your client program to use the correct IP?

Comment: Yes, I modify the client program to use the correct IP address. Both adapters have different IP addresses (As a side note, Is it possible for both adapters to have same IP Address?)

Comment: Does the behavior of situation 2 change if you have your listening script bind to the WiFi address?

Comment: No, even if I specifically bind to WiFi address the packets are not received.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the script. This sounds more like   an issue with how networking is configured. I assume the script works if you run the client program on the same machine, yes?

Comment: The script works when the client program is on the same machine. It also works when the client program is on a different machine but connected via LAN cable. I also think the problem is how the network is configured. But I don't know how to debug that. Also, is it possible that python socket library ignores some network interfaces?

Comment: @user3098466, have you checked if you have your Machine B's Wifi interface disabling ipv6 in Windows?

Comment: 'sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that there's some problem with the OS buffer, but that would be more of a problem if you're sending a lot of data, as opposed to only one burst of data.

Answer (score 1):

Check the trust setting on the Wifi network for the server machine. According to [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731634.aspx) from Microsoft:

> For example, a program that accepts inbound connections from the
>   Internet (like a file sharing program) may not work in the Public
>   profile because the Windows Firewall default setting will block all
>   inbound connections to programs that are not on the list of allowed
>   programs.

I believe by default Wifi networks are put in the Public profile, so it sounds like what's happening here. Since you know the packet is getting there OK (form wireshark), the most likely explanation is that the firewall refuses to deliver it for you.

The alternative would be to add python to the [allowed programs list](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/communicate-through-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7) if you are perhaps not wholly trusting of the network.